# iOS: get image label

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender{
    NSString *button = [[(UIImageView *)sender label]text];
```

I want to get the label of the UIImageView. What am I doing wrong? This works with buttons...Not sure I understand how to access attributes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageViews do not have labels.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. How would I access its attributes? I need to set up some if statements to check which image was touched.

Comment: Yup. @Kevin Brown.. You have to keep track of whatever data you want with the image in some sort of data structure. I usually use a NSDict to keep track of things like UIImage data, URL, title and so on.

Comment: UIImageViews do not hold any reference to user information.  Personally I like the Tag feature that C# and other langues use and often derive a class that contains a NSObject property called tag that you can use to store a pointer to an object to reference when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UIImageView`. Add a string member and property for accessing it. Instead of creating an object of `UIImageView`, create the object of your class.

In .h

```
@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView
{
    NSString *imageName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageName;

@end
```

in .m

```
@implementation CustomImageView

@synthesize imageName;

-(void) dealloc
{
    [imageName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

in the file where you want to use this class

```
-(void) addCustomImageView
{
    CustomImageView *imgView = [[CustomImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgViewtapped:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];

}

-(NSString *) imgViewtapped:(CustomImageView *)sender
{
    return [sender imageName];
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to OOP. Can you give me some more detail and possibly and example? I don't really even understand what a subclass is or how to do it. :/